# More common/informal way of saying "as is the case with..."?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests

Example:

> **As is the case with the path**, there's only one cliff.

(Meaning there's only one path and only one cliff.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As with the path, there's only one cliff.

Answer (score 4):

> **Just as there exists only one path, so too, there is only one cliff**

*or*

> **In the same way that there is but one path, there is also, but one cliff.**

Sorry, my "E"s are sticking!

Answer (score 3):

"Like" is an easy, one-word substitute for "as is the case with."

"Like the path, there's only one cliff."

That example, in both cases, is somewhat awkward, so here's another.

> "*As is the case with* my ex-wife, this coffee is stale, bitter and far less attractive than what I might find at Starbucks."
>
> "*Like* my ex-wife, this coffee is stale, bitter and far less attractive than what I might find at Starbucks."

Comment: Or "just like".